# mdframed in lyx

Tags: lyx, mdframed, lyx-layouts

when i used this code in local layout (in Lyx) i got error:

```
Style myLaw
Category              MainText
Margin                Static
LatexType             Environment
LatexName             bluec
NextNoIndent          1
LeftMargin            MMM
RightMargin           MMM
ParIndent             MM
ParSkip               0
ItemSep               0
TopSep                0.5
BottomSep             0.5
ParSep                0
Align                 Block
AlignPossible         Block, Left, Right, Center
Preamble
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newenvironment{bluec}
{\begin{mdframed}     [backgroundcolor=LightSkyBlue!50,linecolor=LightSkyBlue!50,roundcorner=0pt]\scriptsize\quotation}
{\endquotation\end{mdframed}}
EndPreamble
End
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably you're referring to an error saying that the `LightSkyBlue` colour is undefined?

While `xcolor` predefines many colours, most of them are available only if you add specific options when loading the package. See the `xcolor` manual for a complete list. `LightSkyBlue`  is from the `svgnames` "collection", so you need

```
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
```